# Having issues reading a image file and putting it into a byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So I am working within DbContext.SeedData.cs

I'm returning a method back with appropriate information such as names, id, description. Those work. I am trying to, while within the DbContext.SeedData.cs, read an image file and assign it into a new byte array.

```
Image = new byte[]{ FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read).Length }
```

The error I keep getting is: Non-invocable member 'FileStream' cannot be used like a method.

How do I use FileStream in the proper context to read the image and convert it into byte code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either read all the bytes via:

```
var fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

Image = new byte[fs.Length];

fs.Read( Image, 0 , fs.Length);
```

or use

```
Image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
Image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(image);
```